# Rails app Case-sensitive URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our Rails app, our REST architecture curently only allows for case sensitive User URLs. We want our user URLs to appear as `ourapp.com/ChrisScutti` or `ourapp.com/chrisscutti`. Definitely dont want to be shoveling out 404s just because someone mistyped their URL based on case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely occurring because you are using a case sensitive dbms like PostgreSQL.  If so, change the condition you are using to find that user to NOT be case sensitive.

```
User.where("lower(username) = ?", username.downcase).first
```

Note, this will not change the appearance of the url in the browser, but it will query using non case sensitive criterion.

Comment: if you're asking here, might as well.  It could help others with the same issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This gem will downcase the entire path before route dispatching kicks in.

https://rubygems.org/gems/route_downcaser

This way you don't need to do crazy hacks on each controller.

/ Carsten